# Apache gives error on start Library not loaded Reason: image not found even though the files exist

Tags: php, apache

Suddenly, without any change, I get this error on apache start:

```
   httpd: Syntax error on line 534 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf:
 Cannot load /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so into server: 
dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so, 10): 
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Checking for the files they do exist on the folders so I'm wondering why this error is occurring.

If I change on httpd.conf this line

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

to

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Apache does start but now the SQL PDO driver is not working like it used to be... Any thoughts why this error occurred in the first place or how to fix it properly?

Comment: Homebrew is such a pain. Start using a VM and your life will be much easier. Assume something changed, maybe wipe slate, start over. Maybe a `brew reinstall --build-from-source php@7.1?`

Comment: well... the solution was to upgrade to 7.3... couldn't make 7.1 work...

Comment: Always found those things tended to break... Got to point I didn't trust the environment. One accidental `sudo brew update` and I toss my hands up. I still work on macs but dev is a centos image under VirtualBox. I smile more these days. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Facing same error on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4

Answer (score 1):

you can try upgrading and re-installing the Homebrew PHP version should fix that. It worked for me with MacOS Mojave.

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew reinstall php71
```

Then check if your httpd.conf is linked to this PHP:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

And, re-start apache:

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Comment: This one works. Currently on macOS Monterey (12.5). And this method still works.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @LuizEduardoMPF

`brew update`

and

`brew upgrade` resolved the issue for me. I didn't need to reinstall PHP or make any changes to the config file.

I'm using Mac os Mojave.

Just sharing what worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks.